# Wrong field type in osgeo.org for ogr.FieldDefn('field', ogr.OFTInteger)

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, mapinfo

I have a problem with osgeo.org for python using versions

```
python version 2.7  
osgeo.org version 1.3.39
```

I want to use osgeo to convert `MapInfo File` from MongoDB.

With

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal   
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("MapInfo File")     
number_of_rooms = ogr.FieldDefn('number_of_rooms', ogr.OFTInteger)    
feature.SetField("number_of_rooms ",num)    
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

the `MapInfo File` is built but the field `number_of_romms`'s type is `Integer(12)` whereas I want it to be `Integer` and can't figure out the problem.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

The mif file is the following:

```
Version 300              
Charset "Neutral"   
Delimiter ","    
CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 104  
Columns 19        

[...]

number_of_rooms Integer(12) //i want number_of_rooms Integer

Data
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get you right but if it is the precision or width of the field you want to change you can use:

```
number_of_rooms = ogr.FieldDefn('number_of_rooms', ogr.OFTInteger)
number_of_rooms.SetPrecision(int_new_precision)
```

Read more at: http://gdal.org/python/